# Add custom legend in highchart

Tags: highcharts, legend

How to add a custom legend in highchart like without series of data I need to add a legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize it with an empty series..

Comment: Hi David, within the series i have only two data but i need to add one custom legend(three legend like three label), so how can i add it?

Comment: Add a third one where data is en empty array. (No points) And name it after the label you need. This should work.

Comment: when i add array for third legend the average pin position has been slightly changed

Comment: With that description I cannot help you.
I don't know how it changed. And perhaps you could post example data of the series.